# Youtube Api doesn't show numbers above 1000000 in json response

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am just trying to understand how this youtube api works.And I am confused .. let say you wonder how many videos exist in youtube related to  the words war or love.. if you execute a query you will see that The "totalResults" field in the response json doesn't show numbers above 1000000.I get the same result everytime

[Here is the Api Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&q=love&_h=1&)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take into consideration that the value of the property [totalResults](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#pageInfo.totalResults) is no more than an *estimate*!

Hence, the magic value `1000000` should be understood as an indication given by Google's backend engine that your query's expression isn't narrow enough for it to deserve a better estimation.